# Multiple NSManagedObjectContexts issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I'm having an issue implementing a parent/child relationship between two NSManagedObjectContext's. My app imports a lot of data from a web service that was causing UI lag while saving the context. So in my AppDelegate I created a parent context (master) with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)masterMOC
{
  if (_masterMOC != nil) {
      return _masterMOC;
  }

  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
  if (coordinator != nil) {
    _masterMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_masterMOC setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
  }
  return _masterMOC;
}
```

...and a child context (main) with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType. I set the main MOC's parentContext to masterMOC:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainMOC
{
  if (_mainMOC != nil) {
    return _mainMOC;
  }

  _mainMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
  [_mainMOC setUndoManager:nil];
  [_mainMOC setParentContext:[self masterMOC]];

  return _mainMOC;
}
```

In my applicationDidFinishLaunching I kick off an import operation that queries the web service and saves the results on the master (PrivateQueue) context. I also register for the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification and attempt to merge those changes into the child mainMOC.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
  [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextChanged:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.masterMOC];

  RequestHandler *handler = [[RequestHandler alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:self.masterMOC];
  [handler importAllViews];

  ...

  return YES;
}

- (void) contextChanged: (NSNotification *) notification
{
  // Only interested in merging from master into main.
  if ([notification object] != self.masterMOC) return;

  [self.mainMOC performBlock:^{
    [self.mainMOC mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
  }];
}
```

The RequestHandler class has a saveContext method that saves the master context on the correct thread:

```
@implementation KDBRequestHandler

...

- (void) saveContext
{    
  [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        [NSException raise:@"Unable to save build details." format:@"Error saving context: %@", error];
    }
  }];
}

... 

@end
```

I've verified the import to be correctly saving its objects on a background thread with Instruments. **My problem lies with the child managed object context that has NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.** After the import is kicked off, application didFinishLaunching initializes the UI as is standard. The view controllers are assigned the mainMOC.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

    UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
    KDBMasterViewController *controller = (KDBMasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.mainMOC;
  } else {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    KDBMasterViewController *controller = (KDBMasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.mainMOC;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

The MasterViewController is essentially the boilerplate controller created for you when creating a core data project. It's fetchedResultsController ends up performing its work on the mainMOC therefore the main thread.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
  if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
  }

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Job" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

  // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
  [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

  // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
  NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

  [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

  // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
  // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
  NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
  aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
  self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

  NSError *error = nil;
  if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
  }

  return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

On initial load when the database is fresh and empty everything works as expected. The data is downloaded in the background and populated in the MasterViewController's UITableView as expected. However on subsequent runs, the app often crashes in the MasterViewController's fetchedResultsController. The fetch fails with this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Job''
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x01c6a1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x019678e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreData                            0x002c6a1b +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 251
3   JMobile                       0x00032ad4 -[KDBMasterViewController fetchedResultsController] + 340
4   JMobile                       0x00031d6e -[KDBMasterViewController numberOfSectionsInTableView:] + 78
5   UIKit                               0x0088e712 -[UITableViewRowData(UITableViewRowDataPrivate) _updateNumSections] + 102
6   UIKit                               0x0088f513 -[UITableViewRowData invalidateAllSections] + 69
7   UIKit                               0x006fa6ea -[UITableView _updateRowData] + 197
....
```

Since the crash does not happen 100% of the time I suspected a concurrency problem. I confirmed by noting that **the mainMOC's parent context was nil at the time the fetchedResultsController was querying.** How can I ensure the child context (mainMOC) is correctly set with a parent before attempting queries on it?

Comment: try adding the line: `[self mainMOC];` after you add the observer to the save of your `masterMOC` and before you start your import. You could read [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994183/core-data-changes-dont-merge/23019665#23019665) for a brief discussion on race conditions in a similar case (regards which thread access your contexts in parallel).

Comment: @DanShelly - Yep, that worked! Thanks for the simple fix to workaround the race condition. Is there something architecturally I'm missing with this pattern? I'm still not seeing data in the MasterViewController (mainMOC) on subsequent runs. No crashes, but no data either. Again, it works on initial import. I think the mainMOC should fetch from its parent (masterMOC) which should in turn fetch from the PSC. I can start a new question if this is a separate problem but I'm thinking I'm missing an important piece of this paradigm.

Comment: In your MOC initialisers (lazy initialisation), remember that an `if` is not a lock. if you have more than one thread accessing this method you must either make sure the contexts are pre-initialised or access to their initialisation process is synchronised with a lock. As for the missing data .. i can't see anything wrong with your fetch code. make sure you are not deleting the store in each run (or opening a new one).

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'll keep looking into the fetch problem. Go ahead and add your initial comment as an Answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Happy to help. posted my comment as answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a race condition accessing your `mainMOC`:
Adding the line: `[self mainMOC];`  after you add the observer to the save of your masterMOC and before you start your import, will work around the MOC initialisation race.

You can read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994183/core-data-changes-dont-merge/23019665#23019665) for a discussion on race conditions in a similar case (regards which thread access your contexts in parallel).

The template code offered by Apple is good where you have only one thread initialising your contexts (the ones that are not temporary), otherwise, you should synchronise the initialisation using some sort of thread locking mechanism.