# PersistentStore Coordinator in a multithreaded environment cause "No Store Found" Crash

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

Managedobjectcontext `save:` query on a `NSOperation` subclass causes this exception. I am not sure what is going wrong here but seems like a thread-lock issue. Can anyone help me resolve this?

One PSC is being used by multiple `NSOperation` subclasses , each with their own MOC. Maybe I need to put `@synchronized` somewhere to guarantee thread safety?

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation.

Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

0  CoreFoundation                 0x3018af0b __exceptionPreprocess + 130
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a921ce7 objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreData                       0x2fedd689 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 3228
3  CoreData                       0x2fefef49 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 824
4  ChevronRetail                  0x0006aae5 -[MyParseOperation myMethod:] (MyParseOperation.m:159)
5  ChevronRetail                  0x0006adbf -[MyParseOperation main] (StationFinderParseOperation.m:192)
6  Foundation                     0x30abe875 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 772
7  Foundation                     0x30b62745 __NSOQSchedule_f + 60
```

Additional information :
PersistentStoreCoordinator is kept in the appdelegate accessed by MOC's in multiple controllers

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {  
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }        
    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];

    NSString *storePath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];   
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    NSError *error;

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error])
    {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    //abort();
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext new];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    [_managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSOverwriteMergePolicy];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Comment: Add you MOC and PSC initialisation code

Comment: Don't have time right now to form an answer, but you have a race condition in your initialisation of the PSC

Answer (score 0):

Apple boilerplate PSC initialisation code is not thread safe (nor is the MOC initialisation code).
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994183/core-data-changes-dont-merge/23019665#23019665) you can find a similar issue.

In a multithreaded environment 2 (or more) threads may call the PSC initialisation code.
A workaround would be to add these lines in your "app did finish launching ...":

```
[self persistentStoreCoordinator];
[self managedObjectContext];
```

**BEFORE** issuing **ANY** operation/flow that uses the CoreData stack.
This ensure that only a single thread (the main thread) is initialising the stack, however this negate the "lazy loading" principle that the current implementation is trying to achieve.

The cause of the error is this kind of execution flow:

Thread 1 test if there is a `_persistentStoreCoordinator` and find it nil.
Thread 2 test if there is a `_persistentStoreCoordinator` and find it nil.
Thread 1 and Thread2 continue into the initialisation code section.
Thread 1 reach the line (but not returning yet):

```
return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Thread 2 execute the line:

```
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
```

Thread 1 return a coordinator with no store and use it in the operation to initialise the private MOC, the MOC save and you crash.

To keep the "lazy loading" dream alive, you could implement the initialisation code in this manner:

```
//UNTESTED
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {//someone already initilized this part of the stack
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;//no need to lock
    }
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (_persistentStoreCoordinator == nil) {//check under lock
            _persistentStoreCoordinator = [self __persistentStoreCoordinator];//only one thread could set the ivar
        }
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*) __persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                   configuration:nil
                                             URL:storeURL
                                         options:options
                                           error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return coordinator;//always return a full fledged coordinator
}
```

You could use any synchronisation mechanism you like to prevent this race condition, this is only a simple example.

This race condition apply also for the `managedObjectModel` and `managedObjectContext`.
The solution is similar.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful - Currently the each controller has its own MOC so I dont think there should be a race condition. Is there a way I can test this code before pushing an update to the store? -- The problem is I have never seen a crash during my personal testing but on store I see a lot of crashes.

Comment: Pause threads during access to the coordinator and try to reproduce the race condition you believe to cause the error.